# Run flutter web with docker. Command flutter not found

Tags: docker, flutter, docker-compose, flutter-web

I was trying to run a Flutter web with docker but when I run `docker-compose up` I have this error

> dashboard_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: 38: exec: flutter: not found

Dockerfile

```flutter
FROM cirrusci/flutter AS build

RUN flutter channel beta
RUN flutter upgrade
RUN flutter config --enable-web

RUN mkdir /app/
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN flutter build web
FROM nginx
COPY --from=build /app/build/web /usr/share/nginx/html
```

docker-compose.yml

```flutter
version: '3.1'
services:
    dashboard:
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: ["flutter", "pub", "get", "&&", "flutter", "run", "-d", "chrome"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last image is `nginx` that doesn't contain flutter stuff.

Just remove these lines

```
FROM nginx
COPY --from=build /app/build/web /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and install nginx distribution if you want further use it with flutter.

```
RUN apt update && apt install -y nginx
```

I also recommend place this line just after `FROM cirrusci/flutter AS build` statement.

Comment: @David Maze yeah, thank you for the correction. The default run user will be root in this case.